# What is this type of texture called?

Tags: texturing

I kinda need help figuring out what the following type of texture is usually called, as I'm trying to figure out how to add it over a pre-existing material

texture:

[image]

Comment: Hard to say, it's a texture that is obviously associated with a UV Map. What's it mapped to in the Material Setttings?

Comment: What is the pre-existing material, and what mesh are you contemplating applying them over. It would be helpful if the pre-existing texture, the texture and the mesh would be packed into a ~.blend file, and by upload to a facility like [Blend-exchange}(http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is the ***specular map***. *Specular maps* are the maps you use to define a surface's shininess. Here's the example of a *specular map* I've found on net:
[image]

Here's how it works: First example (the one pictured below) doesn't use *specular map*. As you can see the gloss is evenly distributed on the model.
[image]
[image]

Second example shows the same model, but with the glossiness distribution based on the specular map.
[image]

To control on what parts you want the glossiness to appear you have to create a black and white texture and map it on your mesh (in my case pure black color is a 100% glossiness and white color is no gloss at all).
[image]

After setting the texture as a factor between *Diffuse* and *Glossy* shaders, you have your gloss appear on the desired parts of the model.
[image]

Here's the interesting tutorial about how to create the *specular maps*:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Gqp4bNJ52M

Comment: Don't forget to use non-color data for the spec map.