# how do i add gloss to, let's say, just over the nose?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I can select the faces(geometry) and assign a different material, but, of course, that's not gonna look very good. I don't want the gloss to cut off sharply at the edges (of the faces.) So, how do i go about doing this? Do i have to use an image with an alpha channel?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a glossy material just to the nose mesh...? or, wherever you wish?.  You can assign specific materials to specific vertices, in edit mode.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44934/what-is-this-type-of-texture-called

Answer (score 3):

I'm only fairly new to Blender, but I believe that if you paint the area you want glossy in Texture Paint mode with a new black image as the base (and the glossy part painted white) you can then save that image. Then create a Gloss Node with your newly created image as the Fac input and use a Mix Node to mix it with your skin node/s.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. Unfortunately I won't be able to use my computer for a few days so I can't take screenshots to explain.

Comment: Danial is right. Please see my answer here, where I show how to use this method: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44934/what-is-this-type-of-texture-called

Answer (score 2):

You can use texture paint but for that you would also need additional UVs.

So a much easier way (albeit not as precise) would be to use vertex paint.

You can simply switch from Object Mode to Vertex Paint and find all the brush settings you need in the T panel.

[image: Suzanne on the right does have a special kind of material that shows the Vertex Colors]